# Tally Values of Each Column

Tags: c#, string, linq

I have a List each Object containing a string xvalue:

```
Object.xvalue = "112"  
Object.xvalue = "332"  
Object.xvalue = "213"
```

I want to create a new List that contains the counts of each column:

Object #1: (1,3,2)

```
 int var1 = 1  
 int var2 = 1  
 int var3 = 1
```

Object #2: (1,3,1)

```
 int var1 = 2  
 int var2 = 0  
 int var3 = 1
```

Object #3: (2,2,3)

```
  int var1 = 0  
  int var2 = 2  
  int var3 = 1
```

Is this something that I could do using LINQ?
If not could someone provide some pointers for accomplishing this?

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on how to get `var1 = 2, var2 = 1, var3 = 0` from string "132"?

Comment: By column do you mean each position in the string? That is column 1 would be `Object.xvalue[0]` column 2 would be `Object.xvalue[1]` and column 3 `Object.xvalue[2]`? I don't fully understand the question

Comment: That is correct by column I mean position in the string.
I want to know how many 1's there are, how many 2's there are, and how many 3's there are for each column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you want the following:

```
var counts = list.Select(s => new
                 {
                     var1 = s.Count(c => c == '1'),
                     var2 = s.Count(c => c == '2'),
                     var3 = s.Count(c => c == '3')
                 });
```

For a solution scalable to detecting all the possible values, you perhaps need something like this:

```
var counts = list.Select(s => s.GroupBy(c => c)
                               .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count()));
```

This would count all the characters in the strings.

Comment: Altough this code may solve the current problem.... but this solution does not scale at all.. what if OP wants to count the characters: 4,5,6,7,8,9,0,a,b,c,d etc. as well?

Comment: @nemesv: the OP explicitly asked for a non-scalable solution: having _variables_ `var1`, `var2`, `var3` is pretty unscalable, don't you find?

Comment: @nemesv: And I have no assignment in `Select`, it's constructing an instance of an [anonymous class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397696.aspx).

Comment: Ok I've overlooked the `new` keyword..., but still even if the OP suggests a not so good solution the answerer should help and not just post some code whithout any comment.

Comment: @nemesv: The OP definitely sees the problem with scalability him/herself. Added a scalable solution.

Comment: @Vlad Thanks, that solved it for me.  I do have one additional question, can you do an OR like: var1 = s.Count(c => c == '1' || c == '27'),

Comment: @Baxter: definitely, there should be no problem. But I don't know how to scale that -- perhaps, we need to have the groups which we are interested in as a parameter?

Answer (score 2):

```
var input = "112";

var result = input
             .GroupBy(c => c).Select(g => new {Key = g.Key, Count = g.Count()});
```

After this you can do anything with the values and assign them to any variable you want.

Comment: you actually don't need `ToCharArray` and `ToList`, as string is an `IEnumerable<char>` itself.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I didn't understand the question correctly at first so my first answer was a little off, here is my second attempt, I decided against doing everything in linq because that can get very confusing very quickly, here is a version that allows any sort of chars, and gives the counts for all columns.

```
    private class Example 
    {
        public string xvalue { get; set; }
    }

    //this will give you matches per column for any amount of chars
    public static Dictionary<char, int[]> GetCount(IEnumerable<Example> matchAgainst,params char[] matches)
    {

        //maybe there is an easier way to do this in linq I am not sure
        List<string> flattenedColumns = new List<string>();
        foreach ( var target in matchAgainst ) 
        {
            for ( int i = 0 ; i < target.xvalue.Length ; i++ )
            {
                if ( flattenedColumns.Count <= i )
                {
                    flattenedColumns.Add ( string.Empty );
                }
                flattenedColumns [ i ] += target.xvalue [ i ];
            }
        }

        //now compose based on the chars
        return ( from c in matches
                 select new
                     {
                         CharTarget = c ,
                         Counts = ( from col in flattenedColumns
                                    select col.Count ( ( ch ) => ch == c ) ).ToArray ( )
                     } ).ToDictionary ( rslt => rslt.CharTarget , rslt => rslt.Counts );
    }

    public static void Do ( ) 
    {
        string curr = "";
        List<Example> exampleList = new List<Example> ( );
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
            for(int j=0;j<10;j++)
                for ( int k = 0 ; k < 10 ; k++ ) 
                {
                    curr= i+""+j+""+k;
                    exampleList.Add ( new Example { xvalue = curr } );
                }

        var matches = GetCount ( exampleList , '1' , '2' , '3' );
        var var1Col1 = matches [ '1' ] [ 0 ];
        var var2Col1 = matches [ '2' ] [ 0 ];
        //...
    }
```

**NOTE:**
I am not sure if this is the best way to flatten the columns but it seemed like the most straight forward.

And this is a more generic version, where I am assuming that the columns are just arrays of object, to flatten the columns I just use aggregate and a privately defined class that represents if an object has been turned into an

```
private class Row
{
    public object[] Columns {get;set;}
}

public static Dictionary<object, int[]> GetCountByIndex(IEnumerable<Row> matchAgainst, params object[] matches)
{
    bool firstTime = true;
    return
    ( from key in matches
        let flatCols = ( from Row row in matchAgainst select row.Columns ).Aggregate ( ( a , b ) =>
        {
            var retlen = a.Length;

            if ( b.Length > a.Length )
                retlen = b.Length;

            object [ ] retv = new object [ retlen ];
            //use bool flag to determine first time objects are being aggregated
            if (!firstTime)
            {
                //do every other join
                for ( int i = 0 ; i < retlen ; i++ )
                {
                    List<object> curr = null;
                    if ( i >= a.Length )
                    {
                        curr = new List<object> ( );
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        curr = a [ i ] as List<object>;
                    }
                    if ( i < b.Length )
                    {
                        curr.Add ( b [ i ] );
                    }
                    retv [ i ] = curr;
                }

            }
            else
            {
                //intialization
                for ( int i = 0 ; i < retlen ; i++ )
                {
                    List<object> curr = new List<object>( );
                    if ( i < a.Length )
                    {
                        curr.Add ( a [ i ] );
                    }
                    if ( i < b.Length )
                    {
                        curr.Add ( b [ i ] );
                    }
                    retv [ i ] = curr;
                }
                firstTime = false;

            }
            return retv;
        } )
        select new
        {
            Key = key ,
            Value = ( from object obj in flatCols
                    select ( ( List<object> ) obj ).Count ( c => key.Equals ( c ) ) ).ToArray ( )

        } ).ToDictionary ( keySel => keySel.Key , valSel => valSel.Value );
}
```